# In what year did Parker Brothers correct the rent for Marvin Gardens?

Tags: monopoly

At first, the rent on the title deed for Marvin Gardens was set at $22.
It was later corrected to $24.

In the edition of what year did Parker Brothers introduce this new rent?

[image: Marvin Gardens Title Deeds]

Answer (score 5):

[From the Monopoly Wiki:](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Marvin_Gardens)

> There are some special facts about this one. In the UK Version, rent  is only ₤22, and ₤44 for a monopoly. It was $22 ($44 for a monopoly) in the original Atlantic City version until Parker Brothers changed it in the 1950s. Before then, it was the only exception to the pattern of the third property (second in the case of the browns/purples and dark blues) in a color group having the most expensive set of rents.

Will try to narrow it down but this is a good starting point.

Comment: The reference to the UK Version is slightly peculiar, but presumably refers to Piccadilly, occupying the same space in that edition. However, [the page for Piccadilly in that same wiki](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Piccadilly) lists the rent as £24, with comments on the page showing that a similar correction from £22 was made at some stage. So like a lot of content on fandom.com, it all seems a bit vague and unsourced.

Answer (score 2):

The site "World of Monopoply" has an extensive history of the different editions of the game, based on collecting and cataloguing different sets.

In [its page on title deeds](https://www.worldofmonopoly.com/northamerica/usa/gamehistory/titledeeds.php) it lists the change as happening in 1951 or 1952:

> The next change that occurred to the Title Deeds was in 1951/52. At this time the look of the cards didn't change, but an almost 20 year old error was corrected. The rent on Marvin Gardens was changed from $22 to $24. Marvin Gardens should have been $24 all along, but a typo by Darrow made it into the Parker Brothers sets where it remained for almost 2 decades.

The mistake seems to have spread to other editions as well, and persisted for longer. The equivalent property in the standard UK edition is Piccadilly, and the site lists [an edition dated to 1986](https://www.worldofmonopoly.com/europe/uk/country/classic/1984.php) as having the incorrect price:

> The rent of the unimproved Piccadilly is the same as of both other streets, only £22.

It's not clear when this was corrected, but [an Australian edition from 1996](https://www.worldofmonopoly.com/australia/australia/country/classic/1965.php) has the note:

> The rent on Bourke Street for unbuilt property is $24 now.

Hasbro acquired Parker Brothers in 1991, and re-launched a lot of the international editions (which were previously published under license by various different firms), so it's likely that they rolled out the corrected rent then.

Comment: Do you have a reference showing that the UK Piccadilly rent was changed in the 1980s? Imagesof the properties from consecutive dated sets with differing rent values would suffice.

Comment: @RobertMiller Looking around further, I suspect the international fix was Hasbro's doing, when they took over in the 1990s.